# Jena read from turtle fails

Tags: java, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I have just imported jena libraries to eclipse to work on rdf-s and it is my first try, but I cannot read a turtle (.ttl) file.

I tried it in the following way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;

public class Simpsons {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(new FileInputStream("simpsons.ttl"),null);

}

}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 1 ] Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML$ErrorHandlerBridge.fatalError(LangRDFXML.java:252)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.fatalError(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:48)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:209)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.fatalError(XMLHandler.java:239)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:151)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.ARP.load(ARP.java:119)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML.parse(LangRDFXML.java:142)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTFactoryImpl$1.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:142)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:859)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:255)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:241)
at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT_Web.read(RDFReaderRIOT_Web.java:62)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:253)
at assignment2.Simpsons.main(Simpsons.java:11)
```

Please help me with some ideas because I have no clue what the problem would be as it's my very first try with Jena. I also got a hint from somewhere that I should do the following: :

> It seems that Jena is not so good at discovering the RDF serialisation
>   used in ﬁles by itself, especially for ﬁles addressed with an URL. A
>   solution to this problem is to make a method that gets the ﬁle
>   extension of the ﬁlename by the use of string functions and returns
>   the appropriate RDF serialisation format in Jena’s predeﬁned strings.
>   You can then use your method both for reading input and writing to ﬁle
>   in the correct serialisation format.

but I don't really understand how should I write that method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[The read method you are using](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) assumes that the input format is `RDF/XML`.

you need to use one of the [other read methods](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

So it would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(new FileInputStream("simpsons.ttl"),null,"TTL");
}
```

Comment: Or even model.read("simpsons.ttl") in the current version.  Using FileInputStream looses the information about the file name ending ".ttl".  Passed directly, that information is available.

Comment: Links are broken, please fix.

Answer (score 1):

Following Program will read and traverse over the TTL file

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Triple ;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr ;
import org.apache.jena.riot.lang.PipedRDFIterator;
import org.apache.jena.riot.lang.PipedRDFStream;
import org.apache.jena.riot.lang.PipedTriplesStream;

public class ReadingTTL
{
    public static void main(String... argv) {
        final String filename = "yagoTransitiveType2.ttl";

        // Create a PipedRDFStream to accept input and a PipedRDFIterator to
        // consume it
        // You can optionally supply a buffer size here for the
        // PipedRDFIterator, see the documentation for details about recommended
        // buffer sizes
        PipedRDFIterator<Triple> iter = new PipedRDFIterator<>();
        final PipedRDFStream<Triple> inputStream = new PipedTriplesStream(iter);

        // PipedRDFStream and PipedRDFIterator need to be on different threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        // Create a runnable for our parser thread
        Runnable parser = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Call the parsing process.
                RDFDataMgr.parse(inputStream, filename);
            }
        };

        // Start the parser on another thread
        executor.submit(parser);

        // We will consume the input on the main thread here

        // We can now iterate over data as it is parsed, parsing only runs as
        // far ahead of our consumption as the buffer size allows
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Triple next = iter.next();
            // Do something with each triple
            System.out.println("Subject:  "+next.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Object:  "+next.getObject());
            System.out.println("Predicate:  "+next.getPredicate());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

}
```