# Error message while loading ontology

Tags: java, netbeans, jena, ontology

I get this error message : *Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 1 ] Content is not allowed in prolog.* when i try to load my local ontology file in java through netbeans? Please what does this mean and how can I go about it?

Comment: Have you done [any research into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513440/jena-read-from-turtle-fails)?  Please post any research you've done and why they do not solve the problem (along with a [mcve] to outline the issue preferably).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jena read from turtle fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513440/jena-read-from-turtle-fails)

Comment: Content not allowed in prolog is a typical XML error, something about the wrong whitespaces used in the headers iirc.

Answer (score 4):

`[line: 1, col: 1 ] Content is not allowed in prolog`

That's the hallmark of an XML parser encountering a non-XML (or malformed) file.

If your input is an XML file, make sure it starts with

`<?xml version="1.0"`

with no other characters in front of the `<`.

This might also be the case for an imported ontology.

Note: NetBeans or any other IDE are not relevant to this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Ignazio, Problem has been fixed. I simply changed the format in which my ontology was saved from functional format to rdf/xml format and it works now. Thanks to everyone for their contributions. I appreciate them